# change Cell colour based on cell colour of another cell excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have unique situation where, I apply conditional formatting in range `=$H$7:$H$76` now there are three formatting conditions are applied as shown in below picture.

Now, what I want is, based on colour of range `=$H$7:$H$76` there should be change in colour of range `=$g$7:$g$76`

I am having doubt that is there any way to do that by vba or by any other technique or not?
if any way, pls suggest, how to do it?
thank you.

[image: conditions]

Comment: Yes, vba can do that.

Comment: can you Pls suggest code for that

Comment: Should it paint the whole range, or cell by cell?

Comment: Cell by cell, mean if cell H50 is red than, G50 should be red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that you need

```
Sub PaintCells()
Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("H7:H76")
    Select Case r.Interior.Color
        Case 1 '' replace numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 with the desired color here and below, it may be set up as RGB(), number or keyword
            r.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' this is black
        Case 2
            r.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = 65535 'this is yellow
        Case 3
            r.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbGreen ' this is green
        Case 4
            r.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = 4 ' you may add as much conditions as you want
    End Select
Next

End Sub
```

For better understanding you will have to read about [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)), [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) and [For...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) loops.

Comment: The offset should be `(,-1)` for `Column G`